# Arduino program re-executing multiple times when holding button

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm trying to control an RC Car using rcswitch library with this code. When you press the forward button on time, it should start and when you press it again it should stop.

Problem: When I hold the start button on my remote, the car keeps starting and stopping..the code seems to be re-executing multiple times a second. I want this to be executed only once when it is pressed.

Code:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

#include <U8x8lib.h>


/*Useful FONTS:
 * u8x8_font_artosserif8_r
 * u8x8_font_profont29_2x3_r
 * u8x8_font_profont29_2x3_n
 */


#define S1 10
#define SUP 3
#define SDN 4
#define LED1 11
#define LED2 12
#define pot A0
#define Rfor 11
#define Rrev 9
#define Lfor 8
#define Lrev 7
#define Rspeed 5
#define Lspeed 6
#define RF 2
#define UStrig A3
#define USecho A2

int potValue = 0; 
unsigned long remoteValue = 0;


unsigned long USduration;
int USdistance;

bool running_flag = 0;



U8X8_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_HW_I2C u8x8(/* reset=*/ U8X8_PIN_NONE);

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();



void FOR(void) {
  digitalWrite(Lrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Lfor, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Rfor, HIGH);
}

void REV(void) {
  digitalWrite(Lfor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rfor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Lrev, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Rrev, HIGH);  
}

void LEFT(void) {
  digitalWrite(Lfor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Lrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rfor, HIGH);
}

void RIGHT(void) {
  digitalWrite(Rfor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Lrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Lfor, HIGH);
}

int US(void) {
  long duration;
  int distance;
  digitalWrite(UStrig, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(UStrig, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(UStrig, LOW);
duration = pulseIn(USecho, HIGH);
distance = (duration*0.034)/(2);
return distance;
}

void STOPM(void) {
  digitalWrite(Lrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rrev, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Lfor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rfor, LOW);  
  }

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

 u8x8_SetI2CAddress(u8x8.getU8x8(), 0x3C*2);
 u8x8.begin();
 u8x8.setPowerSave(0);


 mySwitch.enableReceive(0); // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2

 pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(S1, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(SUP, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(SDN, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(pot, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(Rfor, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Rrev, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Lfor, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Lrev, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Rspeed, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Lspeed, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(UStrig, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(USecho, INPUT);



 
}

void loop() {

potValue = map(analogRead(pot), 0, 1023, 0, 255);

analogWrite(Rspeed, potValue);
analogWrite(Lspeed, (potValue*0.96));



if (mySwitch.available()) {
    remoteValue = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
  }

if (remoteValue == 5592323 && running_flag == 0) {
  FOR();
  running_flag = 1;
  remoteValue = 0;
}
else if (remoteValue == 5592332 && running_flag == 0) {
  REV();
    running_flag = 1;
  remoteValue = 0;

}
else if (remoteValue == 5592368 && running_flag == 0) {
  LEFT();
    running_flag = 1;
  remoteValue = 0;

}
else if (remoteValue == 5592512 && running_flag == 0) {
  RIGHT();
  running_flag = 1;
  remoteValue = 0;

}

if (remoteValue == 5592323 && running_flag == 1) {
  STOPM();
  running_flag = 0;
  remoteValue = 0;
}
 else if (remoteValue == 5592332 && running_flag == 1) {
  STOPM();
  running_flag = 0;
  remoteValue = 0;
 } 
  else if (remoteValue == 5592368 && running_flag == 1) {
  STOPM();
  running_flag = 0;
  remoteValue = 0;
  }
  else if (remoteValue == 5592512 && running_flag == 1) {
  STOPM();
  running_flag = 0;
  remoteValue = 0;
}
 


/*
if (US() > 9) {
 FOR();  
}
else if (US() < 9) {
RIGHT();  
}

*/
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because your switch reset the board. The code should work, even if some errors are present (remoteValue is uninitialized).

Comment: I've added default value to the remoteValue and reset it every time I execute a function like FOR or REV. Still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Have you access to an oscilloscope ? If the problem comes from the switch in your remote then you'll need to debug the hardware, not the software.

Comment: I've tried other remotes too and the result is the same. I think it's not a hardware problem. Also, I have added interval of 100ms and it started working...but I need it to be 20ms

Comment: I am not certain how the library is working because I do not have access to the hardware, but I am wondering if your use of running_flag is correct.

If the remote send a signal with value on when a button is pressed and off when not pressed, you can detect the front and end of a on section using such a flag. But here, you use it so that you do not re-enter the FORWARD executing block in the loop before you entered the STOPM executing block if the loop get the same value twice in a row.